# Bulk Edit "Send membership requests to the following e-mail address" 2013

Tags: email, edit, bulk

I've been a lurker on here occasionally and now seek some assistance for an answer I can't find please.

I work for TAFE NSW which is in the process of separating from the NSW Dept of Education.  Part of the separation means that TAFE NSW staff who used to have multiple email addresses, some of them ending in @det.nsw.edu.au have now lost access to those email addresses and must now use @tafensw.edu.au  .  This creates a problem for group settings in our SharePoint structure.

For some years while the two entities were merged together we were directed to use @det addresses as our default addresses.  This meant that when SP groups were established an a person was nominated to receive and action membership requests that the @det address was inserted.  (Why an AD type people picker was not available or used I do not know  #history).

Anyway, the time has come, as the walrus said, and TAFE has peeled itself away from the Dept of Education.  We have discovered, by the mighty power of Sharegate, that there are some 160 groups where the address of the membership recipient is still in @det.nsw.edu.au mode and we need to change them to @tafensw.edu.au  .  Fortunately the vast majority of our groups already have tafensw addresses - phew!

Does anyone have a clue or tool as to how I can perhaps bulk edit any email addresses to change the domain from @det.nsw.edu.au to @tafensw.edu.au?

Thanks in advance for any advice you may be able to provide.